# Out of memory at early stage of boot

Tags: boot, grub2, memory-usage, dmesg

I have a Ryzen 9 with 32 GB of RAM. Often, just after the GRUB menu, this message appears in the top left corner of the screen:

```
Error: out of memory
Press any key to continue...
```

Pressing a key leads to successfully boot Ubuntu 22.10.
It's not a very big deal, but:

1. when powering-on the PC from remote it's a serious issue since it requires a user-interaction to continue
2. surely it cannot be true, so I wonder why it thinks it does not have enough RAM available
3. most important, I'm afraid this can hide some other issues

I've checked in `dmesg` and I found nothing related. I bet this happens even before it begins to log messages.

I also have a Windows installation and this message never appears when booting Windows. Hence I assume is related to Ubuntu only.

Comment: Do you have a swap file configured on the OS?

Comment: @David, no I don't. Should I? I read that with plenty of RAM is not mandatory

Comment: No it is never mandatory.

Comment: Opinion: error messages should always have a source / generator indication, anything else is sloppy programming.

Answer (score 2):

The memory does not necessarily refer to the full 32GB of RAM, but the lower portions of it that are used at boot time. For AMD-based systems running kernel 5.19 or newer, I’ve found it’s necessary to add an `amd_iommu` option to grub.

Here’s how:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Open the Grub configuration file for editing:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/default/grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
3. Find the line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add the following:

   ```
   amd_iommu=off
   ```

   This may give you something like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amd_iommu=off
   ```
4. If you have an option for *just* `iommu`, this should be removed.
5. Save the file and exit the editor.
6. Update the boot loader:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
7. Reboot.

You should be good to go from here.

Comment: In these two days I rebooted my PC several times after adding the new option. Unfortunately, the error message still appears sometimes.